# Fedora installation problem on virtualbox

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

I try to install Fedora as a guest operating system on VirtualBox in Windows7 64-bit.I download Fedora-17-x86_64-Live-Desktop.iso first and when I begin to install everything fine until I see "Congratulations,you succesfully install fedora" page.When I reboot fedora virtualbox stopped.I search on google but could not find anything to solve my problem.

Comment: By "stopped" do you mean the program quit, or you went back to the program's start menu, or what? What happens if you tell it to start the Fedora VM back up again?

Comment: I mean program quit,now my fedora operating system in virtualbox page is tagged with "aborted"

Comment: One common reason for such problems is an incompatibility between VirtualBox and your host machine's hardware. So, try things like turning off 3D acceleration, disabling the virtual network interface for the VM, etc.

Comment: Or, pack the VM up and put it on a file sharing service for people to download and try on their VirtualBox instances, or import it into other VM systems. It may be that the same VM works there, which confirms the problem. That is, a successful boot in another VM manager or in VirtualBox on a different host system would mean the problem is in VirtualBox's compatibility with your host system. There should be no worry about the security of the VM since it's a freshly created VM. There shouldn't be anything sensitive in it yet, right? If you do this, use modern compression: `.tar.xz`, `7zip`, etc.

Comment: Please post an answer if you found one. Even if it just mirrors one of my suggestions.